# Merging three RSS feeds

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xslt, rss

I have a working RSS feed that places points onto a Google map using an RSS feed and xsl. My problem is i would like to merge at least two RSS feeds into one that can then be styled by the xsl and output to the google map.

Here is my current code

```
    Dim rssFeedLoc As String = "http://examplesyndicationlink.uk/organisations/buildings/postcode/XXXXXX.rss?apikey=XXXXXX&range=12"

    Dim xDoc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(rssFeedLoc)
    Dim xNav As XPathNavigator = xDoc.CreateNavigator()

    dlFindXMLResults.XPathNavigator = xNav
    dlFindXMLResults.TransformSource = "/xsl/hello.xsl"
```

I would like to add the following feeds

```
   Dim rssFeedLoc2 As String = "http://examplesyndicationlink.uk/organisations/buildings/postcode/XXXXXX.rss?apikey=XXXXXX&range=12&page2"
   Dim rssFeedLoc3 As String = "http://examplesyndicationlink.uk/organisations/buildings/postcode/XXXXXX.rss?apikey=XXXXXX&range=12&page3"
```

Is there a way i can merge the 3 feeds into one? Would this require creating a temporary file on the server?

EDIT: I suppose when i say 'merge' i mean join together, the RSS feed is restricted to show only 10 results per page, i would like to join all the results from the 3 pages together? There would also be no duplicates as the pages are just a continuation of the results.

Comment: The description of what you want to accomplish is a bit vague. Can you show an example of the input and of the desired output? Do you just mean that you want to concatenate the data from the 3 feeds?

Comment: @LarsH Yes i would just like to concatenate the 3 feeds into 1.

Comment: Since no one was able to help with my original question, can anyone suggest a way of collating the 3 pages of xml results into one xml file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two XElements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892336/merge-two-xelements)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XSL to do this have you considered [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/)? That will allow you to combine as many RSS feeds as you like into one feed.